# Background using props in react.js

Tags: reactjs

Adding background by passing a variable in the input i.e `validUrl`. Anyone let me know if this `background` property works. Also imported both valid and invalid image.

```
background: ${ props => props.validUrl ? "url(${valid}) no-repeat left 10px center" : "url(${invalid}) no-repeat left 10px center" };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it would be done as we need to pass the variable in outer wrapper. If its defined in the input then the styles according to property needs to be defined in input.js from where it is called. Updated code is as follows:

```
const URLField = ({ validUrl}) => (
<Wrapper validUrl={validUrl}> 
    <Urlwrapper>
      <Input />
      <Text>{domain}</Text>
    </Urlwrapper>
</Wrapper>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Write it like this using [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
background: props.validUrl ? `url(${valid}) no-repeat left 10px center` : `url(${invalid}) no-repeat left 10px center`
```

**Update:**

```
Stories storiesOf("URLField", module) .add("default", () => ( 
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}> 
        <URLField validUrl={true} /> 
    </ThemeProvider> )
) 

const URLField = ({validUrl}) => ( 
    <Wrapper> 
        <Urlwrapper> 
            <Input validUrl={validUrl} /> 
            <Text>{urlDescription}</Text> 
        </Urlwrapper> 
    </Wrapper> 
);
```

Comment: Added a validUrl variable. It is supposed to pick the valid background. but some how it is showing the invalid background. For more help have a look to the passed value in input

<Input validUrl />

Comment: can you show the code from where you are passing that value, it should be passed as `validUrl={true}`

Comment: Stories
storiesOf("URLField", module)
  .add("default", () => (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <URLField  validUrl />
    </ThemeProvider>
  ))

Code
const URLField = ({validUrl}) => (
  <Wrapper>
    <Urlwrapper>
      <Input validUrl />
      <Text>{urlDescription}</Text>
    </Urlwrapper>
  </Wrapper>
);

Comment: assign value `true` to that variable: `validUrl={true}`.

Comment: already assigned but still not working however in react console it shows input valid as true

Comment: Or there could be any other alternate solution

Comment: check the updated answer, write it in the same way it should work, pass the validUrl at each level.

Comment: do one thing, put `console.log(validUrl)` in each component `URLField` and then in `Input` and check the result, what the value is getting passed.

Comment: Running it on windows. Don't think it would work in it